# Specman e: Is there a way to know how many values there is in an enumerated type?

Tags: specman, e

I need to know how many values there is in an enumerated type in my verification environment. E.g.:

```
type my_type: [a, b, c, d];
```

I there a way to check on the fly that there 4 different values in the `my_type`?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an `all_values(...)` pseudo-routine that returns all possible values of a scalar type. You can use this to get the number of `enum` literals:

```
assert all_values(my_type).size() == 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Tudor suggested, another way is to use `set_of_values()` pseudo-routine that returns a `set` (rather than a list) of all values:

```
set_of_values(my_type).uint_size()
```

In a way, using `set_of_values()` is better because `all_values()` creates a new list, which usually consumes more memory than a set.
`uint_size()` returns the size of the set as `uint`. There is also `size()` but it returns `int(bits: *)`, so it's good enough to use `uint_size()` in this case, because there can never be more than `MAX_UINT` items in an enumerated type.

Answer (score 1):

also - set_of_values() return 'set', which you can inquire for the type smallest/largest value, and its range.

For example:

```
 var x := set_of_values(my_type).uint_max();

 keep y ==  set_of_values(my_type).uint_max().as_a(my_type).as_a(my_type);

 print set_of_values(my_type).uint_min().as_a(my_type);
```